# Django dumpdata to dump all tables without data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have been using `dumpdata` in Django for a while. The fact is that `dumpdata` dumps all of the data including table details. Now, I have a requirement to dump all the tables without even including the data. So, that I can use this instead of the `migrate` Django command.

The reason for not using the `migrate` Django command because it's taking so long to migrate DB. I have a feeling if I can successfully dump all tables without data, this would be a more optimized but not recommended way to `loaddata` to my DB.

Comment: Do you have a large amount of migration files, and that's why it takes a long time for the migration to finish? If so, try squashing the migrations. If the migrations are straightforward, you could compress all your migration files into a single migration that creates the database tables in a single step. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing